# What is the new way to specify the legacy `inline-block` display value?

Tags: css

A change has been made to CSS which splits the `display` property into an [inner display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-inside) and [outer display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-outside).

The `display: inline-block` value is a legacy value, but I can't figure out what the newer version is supposed to be?

I thought the newer version might be `display: inline flow`, however the following quote proves that wrong:

> Note: Browsers that support the two value syntax, on finding the outer value only, such as when `display: block` or `display: inline` is specified, will set the inner value to `flow`. This will result in expected behavior; for example if you specify an element to be block, you would expect that the children of that element would participate in block and inline normal flow layout.

This states that `display: inline` will behave in the same way as `display: inline flow`. Since `display: inline` is not the same as `display: inline-block`, the latter cannot be replaced with `display: inline flow`.

So what is the new value supposed to be? I couldn't find any other possible values in the links I provided above, or anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: The [compatibility table for `display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility) states that multi-keyword values are supported in **no major browser** at all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Legacy_values_of_display

Comment: @MaximeLaunois I know, I'm just curious

Comment: @Paulie_D This does not mention the alternative for `inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS Level 3 Display spec provides [a handy table](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-value-summary)

It says that the full value for inline-block is `inline flow-root`